# Empty MessageSource in Service class

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mocking, localization

I am testing one of service class with spring-boot using junits. Now, I call other services as well from the service that I am testing. Now , in one of the service , I have dependency for MessageSource

```
@Service
class ServiceA {
    
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource source;

    ... other dependencies...

    public void method() {
        body = source.getMessage(messageKey, args,
                locale)
    }
}
```

Now, when the call reaches `method()`, I am getting `Empty MessageSource` for this autowired message source and when `getMessage()` is called I get No such message found under the code. [image]

**Also , it's working completely fine without running the junit.**

Update : After I define the bean in Spring boot Main application, old error is not there , but due to parentMessageSource as null, I am still getting **No such message found under the code**

Comment: Your test class would help here but I guess you did not define the test as a `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: @grekier Now I added messageSource bean in the spring boot main application file , but now the problem is parentMessageSource is null

Comment: @Ansul Test class code please

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I used in the test class annotations:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

and the issue got fixed with:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```